# Optical pumping, Breit-Rabi equation, how to get hyperfine energies?

Tags: quantum-optics

I'm working on a lab report for a lab on optical pumping using Rb, but I'm seriously struggling with figuring out how to get the hyperfine energies through the Breit-Rabi equation:

$$W(F,M)=-\frac{\Delta W}{2(2I+1)}-\frac{\mu _{I}}{I}BM\pm \frac{\Delta W}{2}\left [ 1+\frac{4M}{2I+1}x+x^{2} \right ]^{1/2}$$

I have not yet taken quantum physics, so it was a struggle for me to understand what each component was and how everything worked and after hours, (including how long it took me to understand the entire experiment :P) I think I finally get it.

I figured out and calculated all the values and constants to plug in and was just about to until I realized that I have only the magnetic field values at transition points (from M=2 to M=1, from M=1 to M=0, and so on), so in order to get the actual energy at each M, I would need the measured magnetic field at exactly that point, but our procedure and set-up did not allow for us to measure the magnetic field at each M.

Even if I wanted to just calculate the energy at the transition points, I would not be sure about what to use for M in the equation, since it would in theory be an in-between value.

I have no clue what to do with my data in order to get the energy values I'm after. I could really use some help. I have never learned how to do anything like that :/. Help please!